# Tiny FTP client with pre-configured settings? - a simple file uploader?

Tags: file-upload, upload, ftp, client, uploader

I am looking to have users upload files to an FTP server using a "pre-configured" FTP client. By that I mean; the FTP client's connection settings have already been set in the client they have downloaded. Ideally users should be able just to drag and drop the files into a simple window and the file uploads.

I have found two applications which allow me to do this;

"FTP Maker" (softhing.com/ftpmaker.html)
This allows you to configure the FTP connection details and add a logo. You then hit a button which generates the "uploader application". This can then be distributed to users where they have to configure nothing. While this works, it doesn't have as many features as...

"FTP Uploader Creator" (devzerog.com)
Same as above, except the application can zip before uploading, can resume uploads and can also send an email after upload has completed. These are handy features I wish FTP Maker had. The issue with this application is it's developer seems to have gone out of business and only the thirty-day trial is available...

Another application is "FTPcreator" (ftpcreator.com). Unfortunately this is a little outside my price range.

I am also aware of options such as dropbox, ftpbox etc.

Do you know of any super-lite FTP clients which I could pre-configure before sending out to users? Ideally it should have the features of "FTP Uploader Creator" above. I believe this sort of tool might be used in IT to allow users to send files directly to an FTP server.

I know I could do this through a webpage. However, the files will be particularly large and well over the limits of my hosting apache upload file size limit.

I have spent literally *hours* looking for alternative! Any help would be greatly appreciated!